# java array nullpointer

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to find minimum of an array. The array contain Nodes - a node contains of an element E and a priority int. Im want to find the Node in the array with the smallest priority.

```
@Override
public E min() {
    Node temp = S[0];
    for(int i = 1; i<S.length; i++){
        int prio= S[i].getPrioritet();   <-- nullpointer excp.
        if(prio<temp.getPrioritet()){
            temp = S[i];
        }
    }
    return temp.getElement();
```

But i get an nullpointer exception when i try to use it. Does anybody know what im doing wrong?

Here is my test:

```
PrioritetArraySorteret<String> p = new PrioritetArraySorteret<String>();

    p.insert(1, "Hello");
    p.insert(3, "Hi");
    p.insert(4, "Hawdy");
    System.out.println(p.min());

}
```

Comment: for(int i = 1; i<S.length; i++) --> i starts from 1? How much is S.length? In this case it seems S[i] is null....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply means that the element at one of the indexes of array `S` is null. Maybe you're initialized the array at a size `n` but filled in less than `n` positions.

Altering like this will probably fix it:

```
for(int i = 1; i<S.length; i++){
    if(S[i] != null) {
        int prio= S[i].getPrioritet();   <-- nullpointer excp.
        if(prio<temp.getPrioritet()){
            temp = S[i];
        }
     }
}
```

That said, you might be reinventing the wheel here a bit. Using a simple `ArrayList` parameterized with some type that you define which encapsulates a value and priority would do. You could then have that type implement `Comparable` with a `compareTo` method that uses the priority, or write a `Comparator` to use for finding the minimum:

```
List<YourType<String>> list = new ArrayList<YourType<String>>();
Collections.min(list);
```

Or, if you're using a custom Comparator:

```
Collections.min(list, yourComparator);
```

-- edited for `min` instead of `sort`. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

start with i=0 as the array is indexed

```
for(int i = 0; i<S.length; i++){
    int prio= S[i].getPrioritet();   <-- nullpointer excp.
    if(prio<temp.getPrioritet()){
        temp = S[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: No because i compare the other elements in the array with the first element in the array -->   Node temp = S[0];

Comment: This isn't actually solving the problem, and the index had to start at 1 to start comparing from the second element since the first was used as a primer for the minimum.

Comment: true but it wouldn't make any difference to the result and is a simple solution to what to do when there is only one item in the array

Answer (score 0):

The array S has not been initialized or one/more elements has been initialized.