# How to declare arrays globally in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a program in java which multiplies two matrix. I have found some error in global declaration of error.
Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    /**WAP in Java for multiplication of two (m*n) matrices. */
    public class PracProg_7{
        static int m,n,p;
        static int a[][];
        static int b[][];
        static int c[][];
        public static void main(String[] args){
            getMatrix();
            solveMatrix();
            display();

        }
        static void getMatrix(){
            int i,j;
            System.out.println("Enter size of matrix  || Enter m,n,p");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            m = sc.nextInt();
            n = sc.nextInt();
            p = sc.nextInt();
            int a[][] = new int [m][n];
            int b[][] = new int [n][p];

            System.out.println("Enter matrix A");
            for(i=0;i<m;i++){
                for(j=0;j<n;j++){
                    a[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Enter matrix B");
            for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                for(j=0;j<p;j++){
                    b[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
                }
            }

        }
        static void solveMatrix(){
            int i,j,k;
            int c[][] = new int [m][p];
            for(i=0;i<m;i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < p; j++) {
                    c[i][j] = 0;
                    for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                        try{
                        c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                    }
                    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){System.out.println("Error" + e);}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        static void display(){
            int i,j;
            for(i=0;i<m;i++){
                for(j=0;j<p;j++){
                    System.out.print(c[i][j] + "\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting error at static void solveMatrix() when i am trying to access array which is global declared which array a and b.

my error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at PracProg_7.solveMatrix(PracProg_7.java:46)
    at PracProg_7.main(PracProg_7.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: Add error message to your question.

Comment: your declaration of a/b/c arrays inside of function shadows static arrays, remove int[][] from declaration inside of functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java array nullpointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007655/java-array-nullpointer)

Comment: talex i am a beginner please dont downvote my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in your getMatrix() method, the array objects instance variables a & b are NOT being used, rather you are creating new local copies of a & b arrays.

You need to change a and b in your getMatrix() as below:

```
a= new int [m][n];
b = new int [n][p];
```

**You can find the updated getMatrix() method below:**

```
static void getMatrix(){
        int i,j;
        System.out.println("Enter size of matrix  || Enter m,n,p");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        m = sc.nextInt();
        n = sc.nextInt();
        p = sc.nextInt();
        a= new int [m][n];
        b = new int [n][p];

        System.out.println("Enter matrix A");
        for(i=0;i<m;i++){
            for(j=0;j<n;j++){
                a[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Enter matrix B");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(j=0;j<p;j++){
                b[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }

    }
```